# Authenticity of host with ssh key is needed?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I've just added an SSH key to my digital ocean droplet using their API, so I didn't ever connect to my droplet through SSH. Their [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server#authenticate-to-your-server-using-ssh-keys) says that I should, after creating, I should just say 'yes' when connecting through ssh, like I did:

```
ssh -i id_rsa root@IP
```

the fact is that I don't know if this fingerprint is from my machine. Howevr, since I'm using private keys, I don't know if there s a risk of saying 'yes' without knowing if this fingerpint is the real one. Is there any risk, even using a private key? Why does the documentation tell me to say yes if that is a security risk?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-find-the-fingerprint-of-my-droplet

Comment: @muru I've seen that, but it requires a connection from my computer first, won't work